# Can I save my removable drives' Bitlocker recovery keys?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I have an external USB 3.0 hard disk which I use frequently. I would like to protect the data on this drive with BitLocker.

The only option I have is using BitLocker To Go. This requires me to enter a key when I want to mount the drive.

As I use the drive quite often and my fixed hard drive is also protected I would like to save the password for the external drive on my fixed drive. Is there a way to save the password in such a way that I do not need to enter it when connecting my external drive?

Comment: @Ramhound How so? As long as you still store the keys on an encrypted drive, you are fine. This is BTW also what TrueCrypt does.

Comment: @Ramhound People are allowed to store the recovery key as an unencrypted file on an unencrypted drive anyway. But since BitLocker is already running on the fixed drive, it should have no reason to refuse keys for other drives there as the encrypted fixed drive can be considered secure.

Answer (score 0):

In CMD with admin privileges:

`manage-bde -autounlock -enable E:`

E: is external drive.

You could also use the GUI and click [Auto unlock this drive] in Bitlocker settings.